# How do I put a hat on 'e' (ê)?

Tags: command-line, special-characters

Since I've migrated to linux a few years ago, one issue still remains.

The ê character features a lot in my "moeder taal" (home language).

In Windows making the character was easy, I simply had to type <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>136</kbd> and voila!

Is there a simplistic way in linux/unix to access special characters?

I'd like to be able to type an ê anywhere on my (or any other) system, not only in the DE, but on the command-line as well.

Comment: off-topic: "moeder taal" is now my phrase of the week, thanks.

Comment: It's called a circumflex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex ! :)

Comment: @Zolomon read the first paragraph from your link, pay special attention to the last word in that paragraph

Comment: Just trying to spread the knowledge. :)

Comment: damm, now your making me feel bad +1

Comment: Stefan, jy's 'n held!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and an underlined `U` will appear. Next to it type in <kbd>EA</kbd>, which equals `ê`.

Found the info [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?p=5743314#post5743314)

Comment: great, I never knew this

Comment: Please note, this only works on Gnome. For a more generic solution, look at the answer involving `Compose`.

Answer (score 7):

In the terminal you can type <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>. On a Windows keyboard <kbd>Compose</kbd> is the Menu key to the right of the right-side Windows key.

Wikipedia entry: [Compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key)

Comment: Whether or not the Compose Key is that key or something else depends on your settings, and is very distro-, locale- and config-specific.

Comment: Isn't it Compose + ^ and then e to get this ê character?

Comment: not the best of sollutions, as the compose button seems to be a  very rare occurence on keyboards.. :)

Comment: When trying to find which physical key produces a keysym (assuming you run X), xev is your friend.  For the "Compose" key, look for "Multi_key".

Comment: If you run GNOME, look at "System -> Preferences -> Keyboard", in the Layouts tab under the Options... button (phew...). There is a section in that dialog for setting the Compose key position.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: In many cases you can press the keys in either order.

Answer (score 1):

May be I'm not understanding something but why don't you simply install the US_intl keyboard layout and you'll have all accents available to all letters (possible) (and on windows too) and you make `ê` pressing `^` and `e`. `^` is on shift-6 on us keyboards, no idea on moeder taal keyboard!

Comment: If you're not using wayland, you can use this to activate the us_intl layout:
`setxkbmap us intl`, and it'll set your keyboard layout for the duration of your X session