# Fastest way to get an Euro symbol at a prompt?

Tags: xorg, xterm, i18n

First of all I'm working on a keyboard using a QWERTY layout.

Now once in a while I need to get the Euro (€) symbol in my terminal (typically in a xterm).

If I cut'n'paste the Euro symbol, it shows up fine in my xterms, which have their locale set like this:

```
$ echo $XTERM_LOCALE 
en_US.UTF-8
```

How can I configure my Linux (Debian / X) so that I can easily (and fastly) output an Euro symbol, without messing my setup? (for example, I'm not switching to a non-QWERTY layout).

I don't care if it only works in X / xterm, that would be good enough for me.

Ideally I'd need a way to configure a shortcut that I can change to my will, to be sure it wouldn't interfere with my usual shortcuts.

Say, if I want to have *ctrl+alt+e* to output:€ in my xterm, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 5):

If you setup a ComposeKey then you can enter the Euro with the sequence compose-E-=, and get lots of other special characters in a similar way.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable has some relevant information (not all of it specific to Gtk or Ubuntu; compose key works even if you have no gtk or Gnome)
See also
[How do I put a hat on 'e' (ê)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/how-do-i-put-a-hat-on-e-e)
and
[Remapping caps-lock to escape, and menu to compose, on the linux console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7670/remapping-caps-lock-to-escape-and-menu-to-compose-on-the-linux-console)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to use a **compose key**.

Ubuntu has a [community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) that describes this feature very well, but I'm not sure about its accuracy when not using Ubuntu. The page says that **Shift+RightAlt** is the default key but it was not for me on Debian (although I do not use the normal US English layout).

Personally I set my compose key to the **Menu** key because I didn't find the default behavior of it useful.

After you have a working compose key configured, typing a Euro symbol with it can be done using at least 8 different combinations. Press and release (do not hold it and type the next character, it is not a modifier key) the `compose key`, followed by `e`, then `=`.

You can use either `e` or `c`, and `E` or `C` work as well. Additionally the order of the two characters does not matter for this composition so you can enter the `=` first.

Answer (score 3):

The Euro symbol (€) is Unicode character U+20AC,
so at least one of the following should work:

- Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you type
  <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>
  (and then release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
- Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
  (i.e., press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  while you type <kbd>U</kbd>,
  and then release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>),
  then type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>,
  and then press and release <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Neither of those work for me in XFce.

Answer (score 2):

One option is make the Euro symbol accessible on the *third level* of the keyboard layout.  This is the level above the second level (`Shift`+`key`).

First of all, you have some options when it comes to which key to access the Euro sign on.  If you want the Euro sign on the `E` key on the French layout:

```
setxkbmap -option eurosign:e fr
```

Here are the other ready-made options ([source](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config#Options-Adding_currency_signs_to_certain_keys)):

```
Option      Description
eurosign:e  Euro on E
eurosign:2  Euro on 2
eurosign:4  Euro on 4
eurosign:5  Euro on 5
```

However, it might be that you are using a layout where there is no third level, like the standard US layout.  In that case the following will not suffice (Euro sign on `E` on US layout):

```
setxkbmap -option eurosign:e us
```

You need a key to access the third level.  One common option (apparently used on many European keyboard layouts) is the `AltGr` key:

```
setxkbmap -option eurosign:e \
    -option lv3:ralt_switch \
    us
```

Another good option could be the `Menu` key, in case you don’t use its typical “application context” function:

```
setxkbmap -option eurosign:e \
    -option lv3:menu_switch \
    us
```

Now you have a standard US layout with only one third-level symbol.  If you want to put the third level to more use you can choose the international variant of the US layout:

```
setxkbmap -option eurosign:e \
    -option lv3:menu_switch \
    "us(intl)"
```

Now you also have access to other third-level symbols like accented (diacritics) letters, `®`, `¶`, `µ`, `«»` and so on.

## Configuration options

See the [xkeyboard-config](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config) man page for the options that you can use with tools like setxkbmap(1).

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help:

> If the euro character is not
>   represented in your X terminal
>   emulator, you can change the default
>   font by changing either the users'
>   configuration files (.Xdefaults or
>   .Xresources) or the system-wide
>   configuration at
>   /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm:
>
> ```
>  *font:     -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-c-*-iso8859-15
>  *VT100*font2:           -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-*-70-*-*-c-*-iso8859-15
>  *VT100*font3:           -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-*-100-*-*-c-*-iso8859-15
>  *VT100*font4:           -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-c-*-iso8859-15
>  *VT100*font5:           -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-c-*-iso8859-15
>  *VT100*font6:           -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-*-200-*-*-c-*-iso8859-15
> ```
>
> In /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm, make
>   sure you replace old lines with these
>   options.
>
> After editing a .Xdefaults file,
>   reload it with xrdb -merge
>   ~/.Xdefaults. (Similarly for
>   .Xresources.)
>
> Note that the derivative programs also
>   use the font resource to set the
>   default font, so the procedure is
>   analogous.

FROM: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-euro-support/ch-applications.en.html

Comment: this is not at all related to my question.  I clearly specified that the Euro symbol was appearing fine in my xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Here (Fedora on an HP laptop, Latam keyboard) AltGr-E does the trick. I'm pretty sure it works the same on my Samsung netbook and my Asus ultrabook (all Latam).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) suggests that (1) if you don’t have a key labeled “AltGr” on your keyboard, you should try the “Alt” key to the right of the space bar, or Ctrl+Alt, and (2) € may be available as (AltGr)+E, (AltGr)+3, (AltGr)+4, or (AltGr)+5, depending on your system.

Comment: This won’t work on layouts which use an `Alt_R` (right alt) key instead of an `AltGr` key, like the default US layout (`setxkbmap us`).  `€` is probably accessible somewhere on most European keyboard layouts on the third level (i.e., `AltGr`+`key`).  `€` is available on the US international layout (`setxkbmap "us(intl)"`) on `AltGr`+`5`.